# Calculation and search in ranges of codes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a question regarding the Calculation of something:

I used to use this function below to calculate the available hours of working colleagues like this:

```
Function BerekenUrenPercentage(OptelGebied As Range, TriggerWoord As String, PercentageGebied As Range) As Double
Dim Cel As Range, Uren As Double, Waarde As String, Teller As Double, Factor As Integer
    For Each Cel In OptelGebied.Cells
        Teller = Teller + 1
        If InStr(Cel.Formula, TriggerWoord) > 0 Then
            Waarde = Cel.Formula
            Waarde = Replace(Waarde, TriggerWoord, "")
            Factor = PercentageGebied.Formula(Teller, 1)
            Uren = Uren + ((Int(Waarde) * Factor) / 100)

        End If
    Next Cel
BerekenUrenPercentage = Uren
End Function
```

But I need some more flexibility and efficiency in my calculations so I reworked the whole thing, but can't figure out the formula I need to use.

***It searches in a whole week of attendance (7 columns) for the desired Code (see below), if found it subtracts that code from the cell and only the hours remain.
It duplicates that with the percentage of Employability (searches in the correct week and person (on Pers ID)) and searches on.***

I Would also like (later on) to enter multiple codes in 1 cell like: DAV4/VK4 or DAV4/DEV4 in the future and still find the two correct codes

We have an attendance schedule on my work:
[Attendance Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZbfs.png) where we note if someone is working, in which discipline and for how long.
Like: DAA8 -> DAA is a code and 8 is 8 hours 
Examples of codes: DVP8, DVA,DVV,DPP,DPA,DPV,DAP,DAA,DAV,DEV,DLOG, VK8,ZK8,BK8,BL6 etc
VK = Vacation, ZK = Sick

[image]

There is also an Table for  [Employability in Percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gymk6.png) Where all the workers are displayed with the percentage of employability. We use this to calculate how many hours a person is helping towards our goal.

[image]

And the calculation of [Hours available table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y2Tu.png): Here is where I will use the function I am searching for.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

> Example: In the first cell of the attendance table is one of the cells i want to count.
>   I want the lookup function
>   cell (in the picture has the value 120) in the row with the code DVP
>   (left of that cell) to search for the code, Distill the numeric value
>   multiply that by the corresponding week in the Employability table.
>   And do that for every occurence of the code in the week the cell
>   stands (top of the tables).

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with expected output?

Comment: Actually the pictures above is sample data, but would you like a example?